# Reload a Landing Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, form, landing-page

I have a Landing page (a form) multi-language, and I would like to put some flags in the corner and when the user clicks in one of them, reload the LP with the correct content from the Data Extension depending of the language. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's possible.

The onChange/reload will have to be done with *client-side* JavaScript.

I'd suggest using *server-side* JavaScript to do the retrieval of the data before the page loads.

Here's the [**SFMC Custom Preference Center Boilerplate**](https://gist.github.com/wvpv/19777e1167d6ac91e2e8) that I use.

I'd start there for retrieving the parameter value when the page reloads -- mainly using one of these:

- [**Attribute.GetValue("VARNAME")**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformFieldAttributeGetAttributeValue.htm)
- [**Request.GetFormField("VARNAME")**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformHTTPPropertyGetFormField.htm)
- [**Request.GetQueryStringParameter("VARNAME")**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformHTTPPropertyGetQueryStringParameter.htm)

Once you have the selected language, you can just use the the [**SSJS Data Extension functions**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformDataExtensionLookup.htm) to retrieve the DE data:

```
var testDE = DataExtension.Init("testDE");
var data = testDE.Rows.Lookup(["Age"], [25], 2, "LastName");
```

Here's another example from [**Retrieve Rows from a Data Extension**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_retrieveRows.htm):

```
<script runat="server">  
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
var layouts = DataExtension.Init("ImportResults").Rows.Retrieve();
for (var i = 0; i < layouts.length; i++) 
{
    Write("<tr>");
    Write("<td>" + layouts[i].requestID + "</td>");
    Write("<td>" + layouts[i].conversationID + "</td>");
    Write("<td>" + layouts[i].overallStatusCode + "</td>");
    Write("<td>" + layouts[i].statusCode + "</td>");
    Write("<td>" + layouts[i].statusMessage + "</td>");
    Write("<td>" + layouts[i].errorCode + "</td>");
    Write("<td>" + layouts[i].requestType + "</td>");
    Write("<td>" + layouts[i].sequenceCode + "</td>");
    Write("<td><pre>" + layouts[i].resultDetailXML + "</pre></td>");
    Write("</tr>");
}
//Write(Stringify(layouts));
```

Comment: Thank you very much Adam :) I'll inform you when it´s done ;)